# how to show the scroll bar of a div in a table using percentage height

Tags: html, css

I have to write a page like the following, however, the scroll bar don't show in IE 11 and FireFox. What should I do to solve the problem?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
<table style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
  <tr>
    first row
  </tr>
  <tr style="height:100%">
    <td style="height:100%; width:100%">
    <div style="height:100%; width:100%;overflow:auto;direction:rtl">
     <div>
      <table>
      <%for(int i=0;i<10000;i++){%>
        <tr>
          <td><%=i%></td>
        </tr>
      <%}%>

      </table>
      </div>
    </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: In chrome doesn't work well either

Comment: this is just a sample code.Maybe I miss something important. Anyway, What I really want is just like this: A table row contains a div with scroll bar and the height of the div must be set with percentage value.Could you please help me out of this?

Comment: You can control the height table using px instead using % .

Comment: That's the only way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this maybe you can implemented something with this style that i did.

CSS

```
.scroll {
    height: 30%;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 100%;
    display:block;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/fido3993/038enux7/)

Update [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/038enux7/2/)

Comment: you want the div control the height? I don't understand

Comment: what i want is like this: A table contains two row, and the second row has a  column. In the column, there is div contains a table with lots of data. For some reason, i cannot change the struct.

Comment: It seems like just what I want, however, when I change the height to 100%, it doesn't work again. It seems that when the height of div is set to 100%, it will be pulled as high as possible to contain the content no matter whether the screen can show it.Weird!

Comment: do you have a live testing?

Comment: Oh, I just run your DEMO and change the height to 100%. Now I run the coding in IE 10 using compatibility view.it woks. Maybe set the height to 100% is a wrong idea.Since I am a newer to web page coding, I don't know the reason why this happened.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `overflow:auto` to the CSS rule that applies to whichever element it is that you want to show the scrollbar on.

The other option is `overflow:scroll` but that will show the scrollbars whether or not the element needs to scroll, and it also shows *both* scrollbars - vertical and horizontal - all the time, whether they're necessary at the time or not. That's why I always prefer to use `auto` for overflow values.

Comment: I did add the overflow option, and it does not work.The code works well in Chrome.I am confusing.

Comment: Are you certain that the table rows are being created successfully in FF/IE? I recently had a scenario where the overflow property worked fine for both those browsers. Not sure which version of FF you're using but IE11 should be fine. Also, are you certain you're adding the property to the correct CSS rule? Perhaps if you posted your CSS too we could help a little more :)

Comment: It's so nice of you.I am certain that the table rows have been created because the date has been show. Here is the sample code with css. http://jsfiddle.net/Kevinlovecoding/sueayq3s/1/ .